# Setstate not working when adding a widget to the background? [SOLVED]

Tags: flutter, setstate

The widget I made for the background color is causing a problem.
There is a problem when a child widget is added to the Background Color widget I made. In this case setstate doesn't work.
Setstate not working when adding a widget to the background?
Why is the screen not updating?
Why do you think this is not happening? Where am I doing wrong?

```
//zemin_rengi.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ZeminRengi extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget childWidget;
  const ZeminRengi({required this.childWidget});

  @override
  State<ZeminRengi> createState() => _ZeminRengiState();
}

class _ZeminRengiState extends State<ZeminRengi> {
  Widget? _childWidget;
  @override
  void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _childWidget = widget.childWidget;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red]),
      ),
      child: _childWidget,
    );
  }
}

//main.dart
import 'package:builk/zemin_rengi.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ZeminRengi(
        childWidget: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

thanks for help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9iDu.png)

Comment: could you try setting ZeminRengi  widget StatelessWidget  not StatefulWidget ?

Comment: Widget? _childWidget;
  @override
  void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _childWidget = widget.childWidget;
  } I deleted it and the problem was solved.

Comment: good luck with your work